# Compose ViewModel lifecycle when working with live edit

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, koin

I have following code for my main screen:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val viewModel = getViewModel<MainViewModel>()
    val tasks: List<Task> by viewModel.taskList.observeAsState(listOf())
    LazyColumn(contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 96.dp)) {
        items(tasks) { task ->
            if (task == tasks[0]) {
                ListItemActive(task = task)
            } else {
                ListItemInactive(task = task)
            }
        }
    }
    val isInProgress: Boolean by viewModel.isInProgress.observeAsState(false)
    if (isInProgress) {
        Preloader()
    }
}
```

Navigation is managed in main activity like this:

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.Main.route) {
    composable(Screen.Login.route) { LoginScreen() }
    composable(Screen.Main.route) { MainScreen() }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I adjust paddings or other sizes in android studio my Main screen composition is reevaluated. Which is what one would expect, but instead of taking existing view model, new one is created. And onCleared is not called for the old one. Is this an expected behavior, or am I missing something?

**EDIT**:
I'm also encountering a crash when any changes are made in code and live editor tries to update them on emulator.

Exception: **reading a state that was created after the snapshot was taken or in a snapshot that has not yet been applied**

It happens in code below, when accessing SharedPreferences. This code is called from init block in view model which is initialised a second time during padding change in code.

```
httpClient.addInterceptor { chain ->
        val request: Request = chain
            .request()
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${get<PreferenceRepository>().accessToken}")
            .build()
        chain.proceed(request)
    }
```

Though it does seem to be linked to viewModelScope I'm using. Replacing it with GlobalScope stops app from crashing.

Comment: A little tip: you can use `itemsIndexed` instead of `items` and compare `index` instead of the item itself.

Comment: Are you talking about updating in a case where you started the application, then updated `PaddingValues` in the code, and your application was updated without restarting? Most likely, in this case, the old view model will simply be killed, and you have nothing to worry about if you do not experience similar problems during normal operation of the application.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, thanks for the tip. Yes, this is exactly the case, though I actually experience issues. My app crashes with "reading a state that was created after the snapshot was taken or in a snapshot that has not yet been applied" and it seems to be caused by access to shared preferences in view model's init() block.

Comment: I believe it's called `Enable Live Edit of literals`, try disabling it in the AS preferences.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, yes, but I want to be able to use it as it greatly improves my productivity. For now, I just commented out my view model's init() method while applying design. But I would still like to find a more permanent solution.

Comment: Could you show me the code where the crash occurs?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, I updated my question with mentioned code.

Answer (score 1):

Koin 3.1.2 doesn't work with Navigation Compose. The bug is tracked on GitHub: https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/1079.

As an alternative you can use [cokoin library](https://github.com/burnoo/cokoin):

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    KoinNavHost(navController, startDestination = "1") {
        composable("1") {
            val navViewModel = getNavViewModel<NavViewModel>()
            //...
        }
    }
}
```